# get http response codes with python

Tags: python, http

I know how to do this with httplib, but I need to also set the user-agent and I'm sure you need urllib to do that. How can I get the http response codes with urllib?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.getcode()` in urllib2 to get the HTTP code:

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").getcode()
```

Full headers with are in `info()` as a list:

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").info().headers
```

Comment: >>> urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").info().getcode()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").info().getcode()
AttributeError: HTTPMessage instance has no attribute 'getcode'

Comment: I think the first line of code should be `urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").getcode()`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, httplib DOES allow to set User-Agent.

```
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'someapp', 'Content-Type' : 'text/html' }  
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host, port)  
conn.request('POST', '/foobar', 'mydata', headers)
```